# Find the general solution of the differential equation by using the Indefinite Coefficients Method.

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$''' + y' = 2^2 + 4\sin(x)$$

Find the general solution of the differential equation by using the Indefinite Coefficients Method.

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle z = y’$.

Answer (score 0):

The method of undetermined coefficients is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20method%20of,differential%20equations%20and%20recurrence%20relations.&text=For%20complex%20equations%2C%20the%20annihilator,less%20time%2Dconsuming%20to%20perform.).

Trying a solution of the form $e^{mx}$ for the homogeneous equation, we find that the characteristic equation (or auxiliary equation) is $m^{3}+m=m(m^{2}+1)=0,$ so the homogenous solution is $y_{c}(x)=A+B\sin(x)+C\cos(x).$

Then for the particular integral we try $y_{p}(x)=ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d+hx\sin(x)$ and substituting into the equation you will find that $a=\frac{2}{3}$, $b=0$, $c=-4$ and $h=-2$ (we already know that $d$ can be combined in the constant solution from $y_{c}(x)$).

Thus the general solution is: $$y(x)=y_{c}(x)+y_{p}(x)=C_{1}+C_{2}\sin(x)+C_{3}\cos(x)+\frac{2}{3}x^{3}-4x-2x\sin(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Set $\ds{z \equiv y'}$ such that we are left with
$\ds{z'' + z = 2^{2} + 4\sin\pars{x}}$. Lets $\ds{\xi = z' + \ic z}$ such that
$\ds{z = \Im\pars{\xi}}$.
Then,
\begin{align}
z'' + z = \xi'- \xi\,\ic & =
2^{2} + 4\sin\pars{x}
\\[5mm] 
\totald{\pars{\expo{-\ic x}\xi}}{x} & =
\expo{-\ic x}\bracks{2^{2} + 4\sin\pars{x}}
\\[5mm] 
\expo{-\ic x}\xi & =
\int\expo{-\ic x}\bracks{2^{2} + 4\sin\pars{x}}\dd x + C\,,\quad \pars{~C:\ \mbox{constant}~}
\\[5mm] 
\xi & =
-4\ic - \expo{-\ic x} -2\ic x\expo{\ic x} + 4x + 2\ic x^{2} + C\expo{\ic x}
\\[5mm] 
z & =
-4 + \sin\pars{x} -2x\cos{x} + 2 x^{2} + \Im\pars{C\expo{\ic x}}
\end{align}
Now, you are in the right path.